# jQuery not recognizing scroll trigger  

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have the most simple script..

```
$('#feed').scroll(function() {
    alert('works');
});

#feed
{
width:339px;
padding-left:10px;
float:right;
font-size:12px;
min-height:400px;
height:100%;
max-height:400px;
background-image:url('pics/fbfeedback.png');
background-position:0 0;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:auto;
}
```

But it just won't trigger, I can't wrap my mind around it.
It works when I do line
alert('works');
On first row so the script is included correctly.
It just wont trigger the event..I have no error in console either.
I've set the breaking point to row one, and changed the #feed to window, still wont trigger...
Im going crazy, it has to be a really small error.

Comment: How are you including this script? Is it in a document.ready block? if not does it come before or after your #feed element?

Comment: Can you show us your entire html page?

Comment: is your screen higher than 400px?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/BFKbA/

Ensure you have linked to jquery correctly by running

```
$(function(){ alert("jQuery loaded"); });
```

Or just hit F12, check the javascript console for any errors. Ensure the code is either in the code block:

```
$(function(){

$('#feed').scroll(function() {
    alert('works');
});

});
```

Or the code is loaded at the bottom of the page before the closing `body` tag.

Comment: Your fiddle _killed_ my FF browser.

Comment: loaded the script in header, im so stupid now it works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @undefined I advise upgrading to a decent browser ;)

Comment: @rickyduck I'm using Firefox14/Mac and there is nothing wrong with it. I advise you to use `console.log()` instead of `alert`.

Answer (score -2):

Based on your code, it seems to me that `feed` is a class
simply change your code into this (Change `#` to a `.`

```
$('.feed').scroll(function() {
    alert('works');
});
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing in the question that suggests he's using a class.  What do you mean by, *"Based on your code"*?

Comment: The feed looks like a `CSS` which is mothly used for the class attribute. I may have assumed that he might be using the wrong selector.

Comment: Yeah, based on the code I'd say that feed was an ID personally. For a start if it was a class then the CSS wouldn't work either...

Comment: @MegaNairda - CSS does not mostly use class attributes. There are many kinds of selectors (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html). There is no evidence in the question to suggest this is not an ID.